# Is a padded 128 bit private key enough for ecdsa 256?

Tags: dsa

According to the following, ecdsa-256 only provides ~128 bit security even for 256 bit private key:

[A multi-target attack on 128-bit ECDSA private keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81003/103759)

If the private key has only 128 bit entropy but constant-padded to 256 bit, then the corresponding 256 bit public key is distributed.
Would it provide the same 128 bits security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarizing the question:

> Would ECDSA-256 still provide 128 bit security for a 128 bit private key padded to 256-bit?

**No**, for fixed public 128-bit padding. Given [ECDSA curve parameters](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.3.1), the [ECDSA public key $Q$](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.3.2) and the padding method that produced the private key $d$, it's possible to devise an attack that finds the private key $d$ with $Q=dG$ using about $2^{65}$ point additions, that is like $65$-bit security.

Left padding extends a 128-bit secret $s$ to $d=k\mathbin\| s=2^{128}k+s$ for some known 128-bit $k$. Thus the problem is to find $s$ given $Q=(2^{128}k+s)G$, that is find $s$ such that $sG=Q-2^{128}kG$. The right hand side can be readily computed. That $s$ can be found using [Baby Step/Giant Step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step), or [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms).

For right padding, $d=s\mathbin\|k=2^{128}s+k$ and the problem is to find $s$ given $Q=(2^{128}s+k)G$, that is find $s$ such that $s(2^{128}G)=Q-kG$, which is equally easy.

---

On the other hand, if we build $d$ from $s$ using a hash, for example as $d=(\operatorname{SHA-512}(s)\bmod(n-1))+1$, then we get 128-bit security *for single target attack* (that is when the adversary attacks a single public key $Q$).

In multi-target attack, the attacker has a collection of $r$ public keys $Q_i$ and is content with finding any $d$ with $dG$ among the $Q_i$. Even with 128-bit to 256-bit expansion with a hash, an attack that simply tries various $s$ (e.g. sequentially) succeeds with about $2^{128}/r$ hashes and scalar multiplications, thus security can't exceed like $\min(136-\log_2(r),128)$ bit.

If we want multi-target security with a 128-bit secret and no diversifier/salt, we need some level of [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) with e.g. [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).

Comment: @kelalaka: I had missed that my reasoning for 128-bit security when using a hash to expand the 128-bit secret to 256-bit is good only for single (or few)-target attack, but fails for multi-target attack and plausible number of keys, for the reason at the beginning of your answer. Thanks for pointing that!

Comment: Where did the 136 come from in the muli-target attack?

Comment: @Aman Grewal: I make the approximation that a point multiplication is $2^8$ point additions/doubling, thus add 8 bits to the standard 128. That's rough.